# C++ - Repeat std::getline() as user integer input?

Tags: c++, console-application

How to repeat std::getline() as user number input like this method:

```
  std::string num;
  std::cout << "How many subjects you want to sum: ";
  std::getline (std::cin,num);
```

Then take user number input and repeat std::getline() many times as input to sum all the subjects marks user will input them after the first questions.

Comment: Loops are usually good for repeating things.

Comment: Ok, but how to loop as many as user number input ?

Comment: Look into [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and the [`for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer not to use `std::getline` for inputting numbers.

You need a standard pattern:

```
int quantity = 0;
std::cout << "Enter quantity of subjects to sum: ";
std::cin >> quantity;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
{
    int value;
    std::cin >> value;
    sum += value;
}
```

A common data input format is to specify the quantity as the first number on a single line.

The data will follow on subsequent lines, usually one number per line.

The `operator>>` will skip whitespace (including newlines).

**Edit 1:  Using `getline`**
If you *must* use `getline`, remember that it only reads in strings (characters).  If you want to numbers, you will have to convert from text representation to internal representation.

```
int quantity;
std::string text_line;
std::cout << "Enter quantity to sum: ";
std::getline(std::cin, text_line);
int sum = 0;
// Extract number from the text
{
    std::istringstream text_stream(text_line);
    text_stream >> quantity;
}
for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++quantity)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, text_line);
    std::istringstream text_stream(text_line);
    int value = 0;
    text_stream >> value;
    sum += value;
}
```

Notice the difference in the number of lines.

Also, notice the usage of `std::istringstream`.  It looks like using `std::cin` in the first example.

There are other techniques to convert text representation of numbers to internal representation.  These are left to the reader to research.

Comment: Thank you, worked as i want :)

Comment: Actually, I'm going to disagree with your opening sentence. I think `getline()` is preferable for line-oriented input, as I believe is intended here. Using stream extraction directly to integer gives little opportunity for validation and lots of opportunity for unintended behavior.